# can we run react on apache server during development?

Tags: reactjs, apache, jsx, vite, web-development-server

I have an existing php project. Recently exploring possibilities to add react to this project for web development. Currently using Vite (as react community hyping it up) for bundling and stuff. I can see we need to run 'npm run vite' during development to run a development server which complies, bundles, and serves other features on the go. But I am also running apache server for php project. Is there any way we can use apache server itself during development for react/ vite usage ?

If not possible? can you please elaborate the reasons.

I tried looking at what npm run vite does and convinced that it is reqiured for bundling or executing vite features like hmr. But still want to know if there is a possibility to link it with apache server.

Thanks + Gratitude + Respect.